# How to fill an array in given format?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to form an array like this:

```
$routes = [
            array("key" => 0, "title" => "All"),
            array("key" => 1, "title" => "Web Series"),
            array("key" => 2, "title" => "Reality Shows"),
            array("key" => 3, "title" => "Singing"),
            array("key" => 4, "title" => "Vendors")
        ];
```

Here, the titles (web series, reality shows, singing) should come as a response from database:

```
    $projectTypes = ProjectType::select('project_type_title')->get()->all();
```

How to populate an array like above using these values ?

Note:

```
array("key" => 0, 
      "title" => "All")
```

must be predefined and not fetched from database only other project types are fetched from the database.
My database contains following values:

```
array ( 0 => 'Web series', 1 => 'Drama', 2 => 'Movie', )
```

Comment: Please show us whats in `$projectTypes` with a `var_export($projectTypes)`

Comment: `->get()->all()` is redundant, either `->get()` or `->all()`

Comment: Why on earth would you want an array where the values consist of an array with the key number and a value? Just array[value,value,...] would do. And if you need the key numbers, use `array_keys()`

Comment: $projectTypes contains:
array ( 0 => 'Web series', 1 => 'Drama', 2 => 'Movie',)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to use example bellow

```
   $projectTypes = [array("key" => 1, "title" => "Web Series"),
        array("key" => 2, "title" => "Reality Shows"),
        array("key" => 3, "title" => "Singing"),
        array("key" => 4, "title" => "Vendors")];

$routes = [["key" => 0, 
      "title" => "All"]];

foreach ($projectTypes as $value) {
    $routes[] = ["key" => $value['key'], "title" => $value['title']];
}
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => 0 [title] => All ) 
        [1] => Array ( [key] => 1 [title] => Web Series ) 
        [2] => Array ( [key] => 2 [title] => Reality Shows ) 
        [3] => Array ( [key] => 3 [title] => Singing ) 
        [4] => Array ( [key] => 4 [title] => Vendors ) )
```

EDIT:

```
$projectTypes = ProjectType::select('project_type_title')->get()->all();

$finalResult= [["key" => 0, 
      "title" => "All"]];

foreach ($projectTypes as $key => $value) {
    $finalResult[] = ["key" => $key + 1, "title" => $value];
}
```

Comment: I want to get the data from database
The routes were shown just for the format.

Comment: Have a look at my edit is that what you want to do ?

Comment: Yes the edited response is almost perfect. Is there any way to start the count of key from 1.
Because right now I have two different arrays having key = 0
 {
        "key": 0,
        "title": "All"
    },
    {
        "key": 0,
        "title": {
            "project_type_title": "Web series"
        }
}

Comment: Just at this point increment all keys by one. ["key" => $key + 1, "title" => $value];

Comment: Perfect. Thank you man!